# When writing to a txt file, is there a way in VBA to add a version number to the filename if there is already file with the same name?

Tags: excel, overwrite, txt

I am looking for a way to not overwrite existing files using VBA when exporting to a txt file.  My current code just simlply overwrites the existing file if it is exported on the same day.  This approached fit my previous needs, however, I am now exporting 2-3 txt files a day.  Any help would be aprpreciated.

Current VBA Code:

```
Sub ExportToTxt()

Dim filename As String
Dim lineText As String
Dim my_range As Range

    filename = "\\mercury\poa\POA CashJournal\Enforcement Lists\" & "EnfRel " & Date & ".txt"
    '"P:\POA CashJournal\Enforcement Lists\Enforcement to be Released.xlsm"
    
    Open filename For Output As #1
    
    Set my_range = Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A1200")
    
    For i = 1 To 1200
    
        For j = 1 To 1
        lineText = IIf(j = 1, "", lineText & "'") & my_range.Cells(i, j)
        Next j
        
    Print #1, lineText
    Next i
    Close #1
    MsgBox ("Data is Transferred to Text File")

End Sub
```

Comment: Tag the time on the end of the name?

Comment: I agree with Solar Mike. Just use 'Now' instead of 'Date'. By the way: doesn't your 'Date' format return an error because of the "/"? It did for me. If you encounter such problem just use [VBA.Stings.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.replace?view=net-5.0).